# How to create unique index only for records with today's date?

Tags: sql, oracle, unique-index

I want to add unique constraint for daily queue number in oracle.İ have data like below;

```
   DATE       QUEUE
21.07.2019      1 
21.07.2019      2 
22.07.2019      1 
22.07.2019      2 
22.07.2019      3
```

Suppose today : 21.07.2019
i can add record like QUEUE = 3 
if today : 22.07.2019 i cant add QUEUE = 3

i tried this one :

```
create unique index hbs_unique_sira on HASTA_BIRIM_SEVK
(case when 
SEVK_TARIHI > TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND SEVK_TARIHI < SYSDATE  
THEN randevu_sira_id 
ELSE null 
END)
```

but i had an error like : ORA-01743: only pure functions can be indexed

Comment: Why do you want to check for "today"? In other words, why cannot you simply declare the pair of `(date, queue)` unique? Regardless if the `date` is today or yesterday or what not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking a composite `UNIQUE INDEX`

```
create unique index hbs_unique_sira on t
(  TRUNC(dt),
   queue
);
```

If you wish to store `SYSDATE` in your date field by default, you may avoid using `SYSDATE` in your `create index` statement.

```
CREATE TABLE t2(
   dt     DATE  DEFAULT TRUNC(SYSDATE)
  ,QUEUE INTEGER  
);

create unique index hbs_unique_sira2 on t2
(  dt,
   queue
);
```

Both of these approaches achieve the desired result, i.e. there can't be more than one entry for a queue per day.

Here's a Dbfiddle [**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=79bdf7951ae2680c680e45744f3ed865)