# Unique constraint based on two columns, oracle

Tags: oracle, constraints, unique

Can someone help me with unique constraint?
I have table:

```
create table vote
(
    ID            NUMBER(19) not null primary key,
    USER_ID       NUMBER(19),
    DATE          TIMESTAMP(6)
);
```

I need `USER_ID` and `DATE` to be unique only in case `USER_ID` is unique and `DATE` is unique for particular day. Let user to insert in other cases. For example:

```
INSERT INTO vote (ID, USER_ID, DATE) values (1, 1, 2023-01-01 10:01:15);
-true
INSERT INTO vote (ID, USER_ID, DATE) values (1, 1, 2023-01-02 23:11:00);
-true
INSERT INTO vote (ID, USER_ID, DATE) values (1, 1, 2023-01-01 12:55:12);
-false
INSERT INTO vote (ID, USER_ID, DATE) values (1, 2, 2023-01-01 03:35:55);
-true
INSERT INTO vote (ID, USER_ID, DATE) values (1, 2, 2023-01-02 06:40:29);
-true
INSERT INTO vote (ID, USER_ID, DATE) values (1, 2, 2023-01-02 18:01:42);
-false
```

In other words `DATE` must be unique only for year, month, day (yyyy-mm-dd). Hours, minutes and etc.. must not be considered.

Comment: Have you tried creating an unique index on user_id, trunc(dat) ?
(don't use reserved words like date for column names...)

Comment: Do you mean like
alter table vote add constraint unq_usr_id_based_on_date unique (USER_ID, DATE)?

Comment: `not null` just before `primary key` is redundant to use

Comment: create unique index ux_vote_uiddate on vote(user_id, trunc(dat));

Comment: After the first insert, the rest of your inserts are all going to fail because (apart from the invalid timestamp syntax) as the primary key values are all identical.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create unique index only for records with today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57128709/how-to-create-unique-index-only-for-records-with-todays-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a unique index on `user_id` and `TRUNC("DATE")`:

```sql
create table vote
(
    ID            NUMBER(19) not null primary key,
    USER_ID       NUMBER(19),
    "DATE"        TIMESTAMP(6)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX vote__user_id__date__u ON vote (user_id, TRUNC("DATE"));
```

Then:

```sql
INSERT INTO vote (ID, USER_ID, "DATE") values (1, 1, TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 10:01:15');
INSERT INTO vote (ID, USER_ID, "DATE") values (2, 1, TIMESTAMP '2023-01-02 23:11:00');
INSERT INTO vote (ID, USER_ID, "DATE") values (3, 2, TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 03:35:55');
INSERT INTO vote (ID, USER_ID, "DATE") values (4, 2, TIMESTAMP '2023-01-02 06:40:29');
```

succeeds.

But:

```sql
INSERT INTO vote (ID, USER_ID, "DATE") values (5, 1, TIMESTAMP '2023-01-01 12:55:12');
```

and:

```
INSERT INTO vote (ID, USER_ID, "DATE") values (6, 2, TIMESTAMP '2023-01-02 18:01:42');
```

Both fail with the error:

> ```
> ORA-00001: unique constraint (FIDDLE_IQTGCWJPTRJRQFSLCDHX.VOTE__USER_ID__DATE__U) violated
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZBBuBjOu)

Answer (score 1):

you can try this.

```
create table vote
(
    ID            NUMBER(19) not null primary key,
    USER_ID       NUMBER(19),
    DATE1          TIMESTAMP(6)
);

ALTER TABLE vote
  add CONSTRAINT vote_unique UNIQUE ( USER_ID,trunc(DATE1));
  
truncate table vote;
select * from vote;
INSERT INTO vote (ID, USER_ID, DATE1) values (1, 1, trunc(to_date('2023-01-01 10:01:15', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss')));

INSERT INTO vote (ID, USER_ID, DATE1) values (1, 1, to_date('2023-01-02 23:11:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'));

INSERT INTO vote (ID, USER_ID, DATE1) values (1, 1, to_date('2023-01-01 12:55:12', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'));
--false
INSERT INTO vote (ID, USER_ID, DATE1) values (1, 2, to_date('2023-01-01 03:35:55', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'));
--true
INSERT INTO vote (ID, USER_ID, DATE1) values (1, 2, to_date('2023-01-02 06:40:29', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'));
--true
INSERT INTO vote (ID, USER_ID, DATE1) values (1, 2, to_date('2023-01-02 18:01:42', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss'));
--false
```

Comment: The question states "Hours, minutes and etc.. must not be considered." A constraint on `DATE1` would be on all the components of the date including hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: will add the Trunc on the constraint defiantion.